# Uploading Image With Facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook

I've put together a script, with the help of another SA post, but the issue I'm having is it's always returning error. When logging the error with console log it contains no properties so I can't determine why I am getting the error.

```
$(".add-image").click(function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        var imgURL="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3332/3451193407_b7f047f4b4_o.jpg";
                        FB.api('/album_id/photos', 'post', {
                            message:'Test',
                            url:imgURL
                        }, function(response){
                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                console.log(response);
                            } else {
                                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    }
                }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
            });
```

I've created the app. Added the API ID when including the Javascript.

When running I get a pop up asking me to log in, and it seems to log me in without problems. But it returns an error when checking for a response or response.error.

Any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still a problem for you, but I've been looking into the same thing recently and I believe that, for this type of upload, FB basically requires `source` to be the image data itself, not a URL to the image. (See the create photos section on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/ - it indicates that the `source` paramater must be `multipart/form-data`.)

So you have a few workarounds:

1) You may be able to do it from JS if you can create a custom Open Graph Object. I haven't tried this yet, but https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/ looks like it expects a URL rather than the post data itself.

2) If the image is originating on the user's computer, you can create an HTML form that submits to FB and have the image go directly from the user to FB without ever hitting your server. This blog post shows an example of that: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

3) If the image is originating in your system, you can do a POST from your server to FB that mimics the above form. If it's somewhere else online (such as Flickr), you can download it to your system first and then POST it to FB. You'll have to include an `access_token` in the request. I don't know what language / framework you're using on your server, but there's probably a library to make creating POST requests easier.